# How do you make the waveform visual wave vertical using Peaks.js npm package?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, waveform, peaks.js

Currently, I am using Peaks.js npm package to create a waveform using the package. The package gives a horizontal waveform and I want to change it to vertical. I have tried using css transform property but, that gives rise to new problems such as dragging the waveform and others. If anyone has a solution or a new npm package with the required conditions, please let me know. 
It says I am not allowed to paste my image yet. So, Here is a similar image to what I have. https://github.com/bbc/waveform-data.js/blob/master/waveform-example.png

Comment: It would be helpful for future readers if you could attach a snippet of what you have tried (and output if possible)

Comment: @sudo97 I have edited my post with an example image. I have the same waveform but I want the waveform to be vertical without messing up its drag properties.

Comment: Do you require drag support? If it's just about the visualization, the CSS approach could still work with all pointer interactions turned off.

Comment: Can you please show the CSS you have tried?

Comment: Just to note, peaks.js recently got an update, using Konva version 9. Maybe this supports a scenario like this now?